# Cannot find EFI directory

Tags: grub, efi

I'm new at Arch Linux and I'm trying to install it on my laptop. When I try to use this command:

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

I get error messages like this:

> Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
>
> grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.

Just want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: I haven't checked every option, but GAD3R's answer looks correct. I do want to point out, though, that GRUB 2 is not the only option. See [this page of the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Boot_loaders) for a summary of BIOS and EFI boot loaders. You can click the name of a boot loader on that page to see detailed instructions on how to install it under Arch. Most Arch wiki pages are pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

Create an [ESP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition#) partition of type *Fat32*. The minimum size is 100 MiB, and the recommended size is 512 MiB. Then run the following command:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp --bootloader-id=grub --boot-directory=esp --debug
```

Regenerate `grub.cfg`:

```
grub-mkconfig -o esp/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: But "esp" is ***not literal***? Perhaps tailor the answer to this particular question? Perhaps elaborate in the answer? (But *** *** ***without*** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)